# Python script over a file using AppleScript and Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, python

I'm trying to run a python script over a file by right clicking it > Services > my service, without opening Terminal.

This is my first attempt to do something like this and first time using Automator and AppleScript.

The python script creates a booklet for printing from a pdf.

This is how I use it via Terminal:

```
pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop /Users/username/Documents/SomeFile.pdf
```

I came across this solution that is working perfectly, but opening Terminal (I prefer a simpler option if possible):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set didThese to {}
    repeat with f in input
        set f to (f as text)
        if f ends with ":" then
            if f is in didThese then --check to see if we did this already
                --ignore
            else
                tell application "Terminal" to do script "pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop " & quoted form of POSIX path of input
                set didThese to (didThese & f) --load into memory for subsequent iterations of loop
            end if
        else
            --first get containing folder, then use that
            tell application "Finder" to set f to ((container of alias f) as alias as text)
            if f is in didThese then
                --ignore
            else
                tell application "Terminal" to do script "pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop " & quoted form of POSIX path of input
                set didThese to (didThese & f)
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    activate application "Terminal"
    tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Terminal" to false
end run
```

This is what I've tried but is not working. What am I'm doing wrong?

```
on run {input, parameters}  
    do shell script "python /path/to/pdfbook2 " & "pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop " & input as text
end run
```

I've tried 'input as text' and 'input as string' running in automator seems to be fine but it does nothing when trying to run over a file.

Please note: I'm still using python 2.7 because of some compatibility issues with other software pieces I use for work.

Comment: Why are you trying to use **AppleScript**? You can just use a **Run Shell Script** _action_  with **Pass input: [as arguments]** in a **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_.

Comment: I tried to do so, but with this: 
`for f in sys.argv[1:]:
 print f

pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop "$1"´ I got an error every time it says: invalid syntax

Comment: If `pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop /Users/username/Documents/SomeFile.pdf` works in **Terminal**, then `for f in "$@"; do /path/to/pdfbook2 --short-edge --no-crop "$f"; done` should work in a **Run Shell Script** _action_ with **Pass input: [as arguments]** in an **Automator** _workflow_ running as a _Service/Quick Action_.  Note that is bare minimum _code_ without any _error handling_.

Comment: Make sure you set /usr/bin/python as the Shell option. That's likely the cause of the invalid syntax error. If you want some examples of python scripts in Automator workflows (including booklet makers) then there are loads here: https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite